# Removing duplicate items from a list without using temp memory

Tags: c#, algorithm, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I want to write a function that takes a collection of integers and removes the duplicates from the collection. I can not apply any sorting algorithm. Similarly I cannot duplicate the collection. I need to conserve the memory and provide an efficient solution that can process millions of items without significantly overusing the battery.

Comment: Telling us that you want to write a function is not the same as asking question.

Comment: In terms of complexity (O(n)), how much additional memory can you use? How efficient must the solution be? Can the integers be in any range? Can you use Linq? (for example, `Distinct` doesn't duplicate the collection directly) Also, the questions seems more about algorithms or data structures than about C# or windows phone.

Comment: @Kobi I guess `Distinct` does duplicate the source, probably into a `HashSet<>`? To me, the problem seems impossible. But maybe the task is to write a functionality like that of `Enumerable.Distinct`?

Comment: @Jeppe - Exactly, that is what Distinct does, but that is not done directly by me. The problem is not impossible - it just takes a lot of memory, or a lot of time - that's what I'm trying to get from the OP.

Comment: @Kobi But part of the problem is to "conserve the memory" and "provide an efficient solution" not "overusing the battery". But it depends on how those terms are to be understood. It's extremely easy to immitate `Distinct`. That's something like `static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) { var set = new HashSet<T>(); foreach (var t in source) if (set.Add(t)) yield return t; }`

Comment: @Jeppe - We are both in agreement. I want the OP to define "conserve the memory" and "efficient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are very short on memory, best solution would be not to include the redundant 
integers in the list in the first place.
To do this you might use an array [0..65536] of boolean (that you might 'pack' 8 by 8 to get it smaller) which record which one was allready used.

Another solution is to have the list sorted, by inserting items in the right place, but not inserting them if they are allready here.  Insertion will be in log(number of unique items so far) for each item, so it should be something like a n*log(n) time for your list.

If you do not have control over the source, you could still use an array of boolean, maybe bigger if you need to, then initialize it (set all to false, then : isUsed[itemList[i]] = true;), then you can dispose of the list so you have memory again, then build a new list out of the array. So the output will be ordered.
If your integers are 32 bits, array would be 500 MB big, so maybe too big..., but *depending on the integers distribution* (is there a wide range of possible numbers ?? ), you might do be able to lower that size...

Notice that if you are very short on memory you might use an object pool to reuse objects.
(you might even re-use objects that you just removed from the list.)